# Dynamically invoking WCF service

Tags: wcf, dynamic, invoke

I've created ASP.NET application and added simple WCF service to it. The ASP.NET application is host for WCF service. The service is running.

The service looks as follows:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    string DoWork(string text);
}

public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string DoWork(string text)
    {
        return text.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

On the client side is console application that should invoke WCF service dynamically. I use following code:

```
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
IChannelFactory<IRequestChannel> factory = binding.BuildChannelFactory<IRequestChannel>(
   new BindingParameterCollection());
factory.Open();

EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:3929/Service1.svc");
IRequestChannel irc = factory.CreateChannel(address);
using (irc as IDisposable)
{
    irc.Open();

    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(
        @"<DoWork xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'>
        <composite xmlns:a='http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing' 
        xmlns:i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
        <a:StringValue>aaaa</a:StringValue>
        </composite>
        </DoWork>"));

    Message m = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Soap12,  
                "http://tempuri.org/IService1/DoWork", reader);

    Message ret = irc.Request(m);
    reader.Close();

    Console.WriteLine(ret);
}

//close the factory
factory.Close();
```

But, it crashes at this line:

```
Message ret = irc.Request(m);
```

with following error:

> The message version of the outgoing message (Soap12 (http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope) AddressingNone (http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none)) does not match that of the encoder (Soap12 (http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope) Addressing10 (http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing)). Make sure the binding is configured with the same version as the message.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Soap12,
```

Instead of the MessageVersion enum value `Soap12`, you need to specify `Soap12Addressing10` to match your binding.

Comment: That makes no sense. Are you sure you recompiled after making the change?